# connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() return null while wifi is on

Tags: android, null, android-wifi

This is my code:

```
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```

but `networkInfo`  is always null..

What can be the cause for this odd thing?

Comment: Is the device connected to an access point? Just because WiFi is enabled does not mean that there is a connection over it. Also, do you have the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission?

Comment: I do have the permission, but what do you mean : "Just because WiFi is enabled does not mean that there is a connection over it"
How can I check if the device is connected or not?

Comment: Well, `getActiveNetworkInfo()` would return `null` if there is no active connection.

Comment: OK, so this might be my problem! How can I fix it?

Comment: You cannot force the user to connect their WiFi to an access point. Hence, your "fix" is to understand that `getActiveNetworkInfo()` will return `null` sometimes, and so you need to cope with that in your code.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Right now, my app is only this small amount of code, running on my computer, with my emulator. How can I not control the connection?

Comment: The emulator emulates Internet access. It does not emulate WiFi or mobile data. I have not tried calling `getActiveNetworkInfo()` on an emulator and would not be surprised if it always returned `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Docs say that getActiveNetworkInfo can return null if there is no default network set. "This may return null when there is no default network."
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()

A better option might be to check the cell data or wifi connection.

Check your mobile connection.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManage.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Check your wifi connection.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo wifiNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
```